# integer/String conversion in C#/Java

Tags: java, c#

I know that if we have this in Java:

```
int x = 123; 
String y = Integer.toString(x);
```

to be able to convert it to C# we must do:

```
int x = 123; 
String y = x.ToString();
```

But this did not work me to be able to convert this code to C#:

```
int percent;
return "OK\t" + (new Integer(percent)).ToString();
```

Does anyone have any idea how do I convert this line of code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `return string.Format("OK {0}", percent);`

Comment: `int` is a value type, it cant be null. its holds the value 0

Comment: Default value would be 0? for `int percent;`

Comment: in contrast to java, C#'s numeric types are actually sane and usable. They inherit from `System.Object` and they can be treated like regular objects, they have several operators overridden so you can use for example `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` and several other arithmetic operators on them as expected. Comparing C# to java is like comparing [this](http://img.motorpasion.com/2011/11/ferrari-458-italia-barca-2.jpg) to [this](http://img4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20100213022144/inciclopedia/images/e/ee/Caballo-Carro.jpg)

Comment: I think initialization is must here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) is probably the best as handles the conversions for you

```
return String.Format("OK\t{0}",percent);
```

Answer (score 3):

The value of `percent` will be implicitly converted to a string when adding to a string (more precisely, `percent.ToString()` will be implicitly called).

Of course, you must assign a value to `percent` for this to compile.

```
int percent = x;
return "OK\t" + percent;
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to convert `int` to `string` when concatenating with string.

You cannot use unassigned local variable. So this is not possible:

```
 int percent;
 return "OK\t" + percent;
```

`int` must be assigned some value:

```
 int percent = default(int); 
 return "OK\t" + percent;
```

or

```
 int percent = 123;
 return "OK\t" + percent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 int percent;
 return "OK\t" + percent.ToString();
```